# Bootstrap Modal moving page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This has been driving us crazy.

Bootstrap modal when opened moves the background of the page to the top of the page - then when its closed it goes back to the right place.

Anyway to keep the page from moving -

So far - updated to bootstrap 6 and updated angular

used

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-open {
    overflow: auto;
}

.modal-open[style] {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Nothing seems to be working -

To see it in please check out https://topserve.ca/order/mels and click a menu item down the page.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following properties

from you `html` tag:

1. width: 100%;
2. height: 100%;
3. overflow: auto;

and from you `body` tag:

1. width: 100%;
2. height: 100%;

this should work.

Comment: Those CSS properties Luis mentionned are the problem. But they doesn't look like coming from a stylesheet. Some JS somewhere is doing it.

Comment: @luismartinez Thank you man. Thank you. This fixed the issue. if we ever expand to your city please send us a message and will give you free food delivery. Nick, TopServe